# leetcode question 437 why also apply DFS to children nodes?

Tags: java, depth-first-search

I am working on Leetcode question 437 Path Sum III, and solving it use DFS on java:

```
    public static class TreeNode {
        int val;
        TreeNode left;
        TreeNode right;
        TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
    }

    public static int pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
        return dfs(root, sum)+pathSum(root.left, sum)+pathSum(root.right, sum);
    }

    public static int dfs(TreeNode root, int sum) {
        if (root == null) return 0;
        int count = 0;
        if (root.val == sum) count++;

        count += dfs(root.left, sum - root.val);
        count += dfs(root.right, sum - root.val);

        return count;
    }
```

In the return statement of pathSum() method, why we need "dfs(root, sum)+dfs(root.left, sum)+dfs(root.right, sum)", not simply "dfs(root, sum)(this one returns wrong answer)"? 
Someone explains that is because "The path does not need to start or end at the root or a leaf "(from lc437). If so, then why we only need to also only check root's children, not also the children of root's children?

Comment: Does the posted code work ? `pathSum` should throw `NullPointerException` when r `root` is null.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid `NullPointerException` you need to make a small change in `pathSum`:

```
public static int pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
    if( root == null) return 0;
    return dfs(root, sum)+pathSum(root.left, sum)+pathSum(root.right, sum);
}
```

Consider the given tree:

[image]

Now let's transverse the tree from the root node searching for a path with a length of 8. 
This can do it by omitting `+pathSum(root.left, sum)+pathSum(root.right, sum);` from `pathSum`:

```
public static int pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
    if( root == null) return 0;
    //check root only 
    return dfs(root, sum);//+pathSum(root.left, sum)+pathSum(root.right, sum);
}
```

This return 0 because there is no path, starting at the root, with the length of 0.
So now we want to check the sub trees. Is there any path with a length of 8 starting at `root.right` ? We can do it like so:

```
public static int pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
    if( root == null) return 0;
    //check root, check root.right and return the sum 
    return dfs(root, sum) + pathSum(root.right, sum) ;//+pathSum(root.left, sum);
}
```

This should return 1 because there is one path starting at`root.right` with the length of 8: `-3 -> 11` 

I hope this clarifies why we need to check root as well as left and right for the complete result.

---

Side note: you can get the same result by checking all tree node in a non-recursive manner. For example:

```
    Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<>();
    stack.add(root);
    int count = 0;
    while (! stack.isEmpty()){
        TreeNode node = stack.pop();
        count += dfs(node,8);
        if(node != null) {
            stack.add(node.left);
            stack.add(node.right);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because by going left and right on the tree we will traverse it. We have to traverse the tree in order to find the path sum. If you only go to root then you will not move in the tree thus resulting in the wrong answer.

```
public static int pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
        return dfs(root, sum)+pathSum(root.left, sum)+pathSum(root.right, sum);
    }
```

What this does is it treats each of the nodes as the root of a subtree on which it calculates the path and by calculating the sum of the path of the smaller trees you will obtain the sum of the paths of the larger tree.

I hope that this helps.